# OpenVPN AutoStart Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, openvpn, autostart

I am trying to set OpenVPN to autostart on boot. With 18.04 Mate I have tried my usual put opvpn config into /etc/openvpn and then edit /etc/default/openvpn to connect all. This does not work, although it worked on 16.04.

I have looked into using systemd but I can't get it to work.

I have tried using network manager to connect on log in, as a compromise, this failed due to ethernet not auto connecting if a VPN is set to always be used.

So, in summary, what I want is:

My openvpn to automatically connect when I boot up.

Thanks for all and any help!

xm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you save your configuration as a `MY_CONNECTION.conf` file in your `/etc/openvpn` directory, you can do the following:

```
systemctl enable openvpn@MY_CONNECTION
systemctl start openvpn@MY_CONNECTION
```

where MY_CONNECTION is the same from `MY_CONNECTION.conf`.

So if you have multiple connections, you would have multiple `systemctl` calls.

```
systemctl enable openvpn@MY_CONNECTION1
systemctl start openvpn@MY_CONNECTION1
systemctl enable openvpn@MY_CONNECTION2
systemctl start openvpn@MY_CONNECTION2
```

etc.

Comment: Hi Matt. Thank you for your answer.

systemctl enable openvpn@MY_CONNECTION
systemctl start openvpn@MY_CONNECTION

This works if I do it manually. It does not work on boot. My VPN does not automatically connect, for some reason.

Comment: I think, perhaps, the issue is, when this command is called it request a password via a GUI dialogue box.

Comment: So the line in /etc/default/openvpn that reads "WARNING: If you're running systemd the rest of the options in this file are ignored." should say "... *all* of this file is ignored" as clearly AUTOSTART is ignored if favour of this method.

Answer (score 4):

Below you find the steps I did to configure my Private Internet Access (PIA) OpenVPN tunnel. I use `Switzerland.ovpn` to refer to OpenVPN configuration. Please substitute this with the filename appropriate for your configuration.

I used Ubuntu 18.04, but it should work on any Linux distro using systemd. I only don't know if the network-manager will override this or not.

#### Dependencies

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install openvpn`

#### OpenVPN Configuration

3. `sudo mkdir /etc/openvpn/PIA` (change `PIA` to the name of your choice)
4. Download your OpenVPN config files, for example:

   ```
   sudo wget https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/openvpn/openvpn.zip https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/openvpn/openvpn-strong.zip
   ```
5. (Extract and) copy the config file into the newly creted folder (here, `/etc/openvpn/PIA`)
6. `cd /etc/openvpn/PIA`

Skip steps 7 to 10 if you do not use a password

7. (optional) `sudo touch piapass.txt`
8. (optional) `sudo chmod 700 piapass.txt`
9. (optional) Type `sudo nano piapass.txt` and put the following content (changing `username` and `password` to the values appropriate for your configuration)

   ```
   username
   password
   ```
10. (optional) Type `sudo nano Switzerland.ovpn` and change the `auth-user-pass` line to `auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/PIA/piapass.txt`
11. Test the connection `sudo openvpn Switzerland.ovpn`

#### Systemd Startup Service Setup

Change `piavpn.service` for whatever name you would like your startup OpenVPN connection service to have.

12. `cd /etc/systemd/system/`
13. `sudo touch piavpn.service`
14. `sudo chmod 644 piavpn.service`
15. Type `sudo nano piavpn.service` and put the following content (make sure to adapt the line starting with `ExecStart` to match your configuration):

    ```
    [Unit]
    Description=Private Internet Access VPN (Swiss)
    After=multi-user.target

    [Service]
    Type=idle
    ExecStart=/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/PIA/Switzerland.ovpn

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
    ```
16. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
17. `sudo systemctl enable piavpn.service`
18. `sudo reboot`

After the reboot your OpenVPN connection should be set up automatically on boot.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed @xm88, you want to automatically provide credentials at boot time when openvpn service is started up without user interaction or typing

In your oven config file (.conf on raspbian, but whichever extension is needed in your case)

```
    client
...
    auth-user-pass $yourCredentialsFile
    [some more config]
    <ca>
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
    etc etc
```

And right next to your config file, a plain text file named **$yourCredentialsFile** which will contain:

```
username
password
```

I must advise this is not best practice in terms of security, because credentials are plain and available to any user who has access to your openvpn config dir `/etc/openvpn`, but this will allow openvpn service to auto login when started up at boot time.

Comment: I guess that the specific question is: how to have it auto start at boot time.